# storing multi-dimensional arrays in c

Tags: c++, c, interpreted-language

I am working on a simple lisp-style pre-processor language.
In the API i want users to be able to pass arrays of any dimension and size to the pre-processor which can be manipulated using the language.
Currently i have an enum of types;

```
typedef enum LISP_TYPE
{
  LT_UINT,
  LT_FLOAT,
  LT_ARRAY
  ...,
  ...
} _LISP_TYPE;
```

I am having trouble finding an efficient and easy to use method of storing arrays and also accessing them.
There is another structure i use specifically for arrays;

```
typedef struct _lisp_array
{
  LISP_TYPE type;
  unsigned int length;
  void* data;

} lisp_array;
```

When the pre-processor See's a list atom with type LT_ARRAY, it will convert its `void*`(cdr in lisp terms) to the above structure. Where i am having problems is figuring out how to access multi-dimensional arrays. I have thought of calculating a step value to traverse the array but can i guarantee that all arrays passed will be contiguously allocated?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply use c++ templates ?

Answer (score 0):

C built-in (singe and multi-dimensional) arrays are guaranteed to be stored in one contiguous region of memory in row-major mode. This may not answer your question, however. What is the expected layout of the data structure pointed to by _lisp_array::data member?

Comment: The expected layout depends on the _lisp_array::type. if this is FLOAT,CHAR,INT or any other type then the data will be an array of these types. If the type is ARRAY, Then it should signify multiple dimensions. this is where i'm stuck, how should i represent this? btw i am expecting dynamically allocated arrays as well as static contiguous ones.

Comment: When it is an array type (which you did not show), what is the expected layout?

Comment: As i said, I haven't got that far. I was thinking another lisp_array pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing the interpreter, it's up to you to decide on the representation and make the array contiguous - that is, if you need it to be contiguous. If you make it contiguous, you can access elements by, for example (assuming zero-based indices a, b, c... and dimension size sa, sb, sc...):

```
(a*sb + b) * sc + c   ... (row major order)
(c * sb + b) * sa + a ... (column major order)
```

There are other ways of representing arrays, of course - you could use arrays-of-pointers-to-arrays, etc. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages; without any specifics on the use case, if the bounds of the array are fixed, and the array is not expected to be sparse, then a contiguous buffer is usually a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how lisp-like you wanted to make it, really.  Lisp doesn't have the strict definition of multi-dimensional arrays you're thinking of - everything is either an atom or a list.  The closest thing it would have is an array of arrays:

```
((1 2 3) (4) (5 6))
```

Note, though, that the sub-arrays aren't the same length.  But it's inherently lispy that they don't have to be, and I don't think there's a way to force the issue...

If you need strictly "rectangular" arrays this won't work, obviously, but if you've got wiggle-room, this is how I'd implement it - it's a nice, clean structure (check out the [Wikipedia page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) for more details).

Cheers!